# python: заменить значение по ключу и вернуть словарь

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари, copy

стоит задача:

есть словарь `node = {'T': '', 'V': 0, 'E': []}`

необходимо вернуть данный словарь, но с заменённым значением по ключу `E`

можно сделать так:

```
return {'T': node['T'], 'V': node['V']: 'E': [1, 2]}
```

можно так:

```
node['E'] = [1, 2]
return node
```

или даже так (по идее самый надежный):

```
new = copy.deepcopy(node)
new ['E'] = [1, 2]
return new
```

Такой вопрос - а можно ли как-нибудь красиво сделать это в 1 строчку и без уж слишком лишнего функционала, что-то подобное как в JS:

```
return {...node, 'E': [1, 2]}
```

Comment: `{ **node, 'E':[1,2] }` - правда, без копирования вложенных объектов.

Comment: т.е. внутренние объёкты как ссылки будут? или исчезнут? если node - узел дерева

Comment: Будут ссылками. Если нужно, скопируйте весь результат `copy.deepcopy( { **node, 'E':[1,2] } )`.

Comment: супер, то что надо!!!

Comment: по идее нагляднее даже так: `{**copy.deepcopy(node), 'E':[1,2]}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Предисловие

Официальная [документация](https://docs.python.org/3/) Python 3 содержит раздел '[Built-in Types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#)', в котором описываются стандартные типы данных, встроенные в интерпретатор.

В подразделе '[Mapping Types — dict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict)' можно изучить список операций, которые поддерживают словари.

### Ответ

Одним из нововведений в Python 3.9 выступает `merge operator` для `встроенного dict-класса`.

Официальная документация гласит:

> **d | other**
>
> > Create a new dictionary with the merged keys and values of d and other, which must both be dictionaries. The values of other take priority when d and other share keys.
>
> *New in version 3.9.*

Т. е. результатом будет выступать новый словарь с объединенными ключами и значениями из *словарей* `d` и `other`. Значения словаря `other` будут в приоритете в случае коллизии ключей.

### Пример

```py
>>> d = {'spam':  1, 'eggs': 2, 'cheese': 3}
>>> e = {'cheese': 'cheddar', 'aardvark': 'Ethel'}

>>> d | e
{'spam': 1, 'eggs': 2, 'cheese': 'cheddar', 'aardvark': 'Ethel'}

>>> e | d
{'cheese': 3, 'aardvark': 'Ethel', 'spam': 1, 'eggs': 2}
```

### Примечание

В случае возникновения каких-либо вопросов, обратитесь к [PEP 584 – Add Union Operators To dict](https://peps.python.org/pep-0584/)